# Python: simplest way to make a function return next line from a file

Tags: python, file, line

So basically, im searching for the simplest way to make a function return a new line each time its called

lets say i have a file containing this

```
6
2d
7d
ga
fda
7
@
```

the first time the function() is called, it return 6 then 2d then 7d then ga etc.

sorry for ym english thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can use a generator for the file:

```
def fileLines(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        for line in f:
            yield line

gen = fileLines('blah')

# to get the next line, you can call next(gen):

line = next(gen)     # line will contain 5
nextLine = next(gen) # nextLine will contain 2d
```

Comment: A file object should already act as a generator.

Comment: We could yield `line.strip()` to make it kind of useful.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the "yield" statement that will do exactly what you need.